# Creating a Custom Content Editor WebPart in SharePoint 2013

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2013, web-parts

I have requirement and need a suggestion from you guys. In the below I will state my requirement.

I have a SharePoint 2013 Publishing Site.
This has custom master pages build using some HTML files and custom page layouts.
The client needs to follow the styles according to the clients style guide. For the master pages and the page layouts the styling was not an issue.
The content needed to be follow the same styles as guided by the clients style guide. So we have used 'Script editor' web part to insert the content. But this has a bad influence only the technically skilled users can insert the content.
But if we use the Content editor web part we do not need to use HTML code to insert the content. But the issue is the default content editor web part does not has the styles that relevant to the clients style guide. 
Can we create an our own content editor web part that reflect the clients style guide using Visual studio ?
I hope these information is enough to get an idea.

Thanks and regards,

Chiranthaka

Comment: You don't need to create a new content editor webpart, you could just use your own .css file to style the existing webpart and reference it in your custom page layout. (Given that you don't need the old content editor webpart existing in parallel)

Comment: Could you elaborate the solution? Like using the existing css file and so on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok guys! Many thanks for your help. I found several articles regarding creating a custom SharePoint 'Custom Content Editor' web part using Visual Studio 2013 and SharePoint 2013 Enterprise. These artcles are somewhat old but we can use them for our purpose. 
I will post the URLs for those articles.

[Creating a Custom Web Part Editor in SharePoint 2010](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/hh228018%28v=office.14%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)

[Custom Content Editor Web Part for SharePoint](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/31990/Custom-Content-Editor-Web-Part-for-SharePoint)